# Toggle case of next letter in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to be able to toggle the case of the letter under the point. To that end, I wrote this:

```
(defun toggle-case-next-letter ()
  "Toggles the case of the next letter, then moves the point forward one character"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((p (point))
        (upcased (upcasep (char-after)))
        (f (if upcased 'downcase-region 'upcase-region)))
    (progn
      (f p (+ 1 p))
      (forward-char))))
```

However, when I run it (I've bound it to `M-#`), I get `progn: Symbol's function definition is void: f`. I assume this means `f` isn't bound, but I'm not sure.

Upcasep is defined as:

```
(defun upcasep (c) (eq c (upcase c)))
```

Is the problem in the let binding, or something else? (Also, if there's a better way to do this, that'd be nice as well).

Note that originally I had `(upcased (upcasep (buffer-substring-no-properties p (+ 1 p))))`, which I've corrected to `(upcased (upcasep (char-after))`, because using `upcasep` as defined above is always `nil` for strings (so I couldn't downcase again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a typical case of lisp-1 / lisp-2 confusion. Here's a fix (just a `funcall`):

```
(defun toggle-case-next-letter ()
  "Toggles the case of the next letter, then moves the point forward one character"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((p (point))
        (upcased (char-upcasep (buffer-substring-no-properties p (+ 1 p))))
        (f (if upcased 'downcase-region 'upcase-region)))
    (progn
      (funcall f p (+ 1 p))
      (forward-char))))
```

And here's what I have:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C->") 'upcase-word-toggle)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'capitalize-word-toggle)

(defun char-upcasep (letter)
  (eq letter (upcase letter)))

(defun capitalize-word-toggle ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (car
                (save-excursion
                  (backward-word)
                  (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))))
    (if start
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char start)
          (funcall
           (if (char-upcasep (char-after))
               'downcase-region
             'upcase-region)
           start (1+ start)))
      (capitalize-word -1))))

(defun upcase-word-toggle ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))
        beg end
        regionp)
    (if (eq this-command last-command)
        (setq regionp (get this-command 'regionp))
      (put this-command 'regionp nil))
    (cond
      ((or (region-active-p) regionp)
       (setq beg (region-beginning)
             end (region-end))
       (put this-command 'regionp t))
      (bounds
       (setq beg (car bounds)
             end (cdr bounds)))
      (t
       (setq beg (point)
             end (1+ beg))))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (1- beg))
      (and (re-search-forward "[A-Za-z]" end t)
           (funcall (if (char-upcasep (char-before))
                        'downcase-region
                      'upcase-region)
                    beg end)))))
```

Comment: That makes it work to upcase the letter under the point, but it doesn't downcase them again - seems that `(upcasep "D")` is `nil`, even though `(upcasep ?D)` is `t`. However, we seem to have the same definition for `upcasep`...

Comment: `"D"` is a string. `?D` is a char. Strings are compared with `equal` (expensive, that's why I don't use it).
Chars are compared with `eq` (cheap).

Comment: So comparing something that `buffer-substring` returns using `eq` is always going to be nil?

Comment: Yes, unless two strings are same object. A bunch of other languages
have the same notion of strict and non-strict equality.

Comment: You do not need a `progn` under `let`.

Comment: `?D` is actually an integer.

Comment: Yes, chars are integers in elisp as well as in C.

Comment: To downcase a capital is it simply a case of swapping `eq` to `equal` in the definition of `upcasep`?

Comment: Nope. ?c is 99 and ?C is 67. `eq` and `equal` are same for numbers.

Comment: Oh, so could you suggest the correct way to lowercase a capital then please?

Comment: `(eq ?c (downcase ?C))`

Comment: Ah but how to lowercase a capital OR uppercase a lowercase letter? Basically this function is only doing the latter for me, or with your comment I can lowercase a capital. Ideally one function could swap/invert/toggle the case of the letter under the point. A bit like using a `~` in vi.

Comment: `(defun toggle-case (c) (if (eq c (downcase c)) (upcase c) (downcase c)))`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get @abo-abo's answer working for me but using his comments I was able to google better and found the following at http://chneukirchen.org/dotfiles/.emacs

```
(defun chris2-toggle-case ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((char (following-char)))
    (if (eq char (upcase char))
        (insert-char (downcase char) 1 t)
      (insert-char (upcase char) 1 t)))
  (delete-char 1 nil)
  (backward-char))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-#") 'chris2-toggle-case)
```

This answers the original question if you remove `(backward-char)`.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old question, but having stumbled upon the same problem recently, I'd like to suggest a simpler solution.

I start with a pure function for toggling character case, based on char code property inspection:

```
(cl-defun toggle-char-case (c)
  (cl-case (get-char-code-property c 'general-category)
      (Lu (downcase c))
      (Ll (upcase c))
      (t c)))
```

I then use it from within an interactive function operating at point:

```
(cl-defun toggle-char-case-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((new (toggle-char-case (char-after))))
    (delete-char 1)
    (insert new)))
```

I then bound this interactive function to a keybinding of my choice:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-c") 'toggle-char-case-at-point)
```

The way this function operates is, after toggling the case it advances the point by one. So calling it repeatedly will toggle the cases of a sequence of chars. One could make it keep the point unchanged - that would require adding `(backward-char)` to the body.